# Update for the terminal package always fails

Tags: apt, updates

I'm trying to update my Ubuntu 14.10 
but for the last few weeks the package terminal always fails while the rest works fine.

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

(Reading database ... 309452 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-terminal-data_3.12.3-0ubuntu1~utopic2_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-terminal-data (3.12.3-0ubuntu1~utopic2) over (3.12.3-0ubuntu1~trusty1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-terminal-data_3.12.3-0ubuntu1~utopic2_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/gnome-shell/search-providers/gnome-terminal-search-provider.ini', which is also in package gnome-terminal 3.12.3-0ubuntu1~trusty1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-terminal_3.12.3-0ubuntu1~utopic2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-terminal (3.12.3-0ubuntu1~utopic2) over (3.12.3-0ubuntu1~trusty1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-terminal_3.12.3-0ubuntu1~utopic2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/appdata/gnome-terminal.appdata.xml', which is also in package gnome-terminal-data 3.12.3-0ubuntu1~trusty1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-2) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.10.20140925-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.55ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.42.1-1~ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.42.1-1~ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-terminal-data_3.12.3-0ubuntu1~utopic2_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-terminal_3.12.3-0ubuntu1~utopic2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So what is the wrong here?

Comment: `trying to overwrite '/usr/share/appdata/gnome-terminal.appdata.xml', which is also in package gnome-terminal-data 3.12.3-0ubuntu1~trusty1`. The solution might be to get rid of `gnome-terminal` and `gnome-terminal-data`, and then reinstall `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: tried that and didn't work

Comment: Can you [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/560602/edit) your question and paste what happens when you run `sudo apt-get remove gnome-terminal` followed by `sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal` (assuming the first command is successful)? I thought this would work.

Comment: bad suggestion the terminal is now removed and can't be installed

Comment: Press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get to a tty.  Press Ctrl+Alt+F7 to get back.

Comment: did that before and didn't work .I use xterm now

Comment: ok issue solved using the mistake done here :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer came by mistake; I just removed `gnome-terminal`

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-terminal
```

then the update was successful for `gnome-terminal-data`

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then I reinstalled `gnome-terminal`

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have at least one Trusty (14.04) source in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` , or you previously had a partial-upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10. Since you don't seem to have a long list of updates, we can assume the former.

```
Unpacking gnome-terminal-data (3.12.3-0ubuntu1~utopic2) over (3.12.3-0ubuntu1~trusty1) ...
Unpacking gnome-terminal (3.12.3-0ubuntu1~utopic2) over (3.12.3-0ubuntu1~trusty1) ...
```

Check your **System Settings --> Software & Updates**, and uncheck those older sources.